# Showing that a cube root approximation has no decrementing function/loop variant

Tags: numerical-methods, approximation

I'm not sure if I've phrased the title correctly, but my question is about the following (Python) code that tries to approximate the cube root of some number `x`:

```
x = 10000
epsilon = 0.1
step = 0.01
ans = 0.0

while abs(ans**3 - x) >= epsilon:
    ans = ans + step
    print(ans)
```

Running this code for x = 10000 results in an infinite loop.

I understand that this happens because the step size is too big in this case (so it ends up skipping over the cube root of 10000). But it's troubling me that I would not have been able to foresee this just by looking at the code alone and **I was wondering if there was a way to show that this loop does *not* terminate for all values of `x`?**

I'm also not sure how the author would have known to try `x = 10000` - **how can I find other values that cause the loop to fail?**

Comment: Take any "large" $n\in\Bbb N$ and take $x$ such that  $x-0.2<(n/100)^3<x-0.01$... ($x$ need not be an integer). After $n$ passes thru the loop, "ans" will be $A=n/100 $ and the next value will be $B=A+0.01$. But $B^3-A^3$ can be arbitrarily large, as there is no upper limit to $n,$ so we will get $B^3>x+0.1$ and $A^3<x-0.1.$

Comment: Thanks @DanielWainfleet, where do the bounds of the $x−0.2<(n/100)^3<x−0.01$ interval come from?

Comment: Thanks @LutzLehmann, I've fixed the typo.

Comment: The difference between the cubes of $a$ and $a+h$ is $3a^2h+3ah^2+h^3$. The first term dominates and can become rather large. To guarantee a hit in the loop you need to make $h$ so small that this term is smaller than twice the error tolerance.

Comment: Thank you @LutzLehmann. I've never done any numerical analysis before, so I'm not sure I understand your comments fully, but would you know the name of this method? I'd like to read about it but all the resources I have come across so far only talk about Newton-Raphson and bisectional search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying out, successively, numbers of the form $a=k·h$. The gap between the cubes of two neighboring elements of this sequence is $$(a+h)^3-a^3=h·(3a^2+3ah+h^2).$$ The cubes, plusminus the tolerance $\epsilon$, form a "net" in which you aim to catch the input number $x$. For that to work, the net should have no gaps around $x$. So you need
$$
a^3+ϵ > (a+h)^3-ϵ\iff h<\fracϵ{3a^2+3ah+h^2}.
$$
Now we do not know what $a$ is, as that is the output to be computed. One can insert an upper bound for $a$ and $h<1$ into the right side, or use that as $x>27$ then $a>3$ to establish the stricter condition $h\le \fracϵ{x}$.

---

Of course, this gives unrealistic step sizes. So just use the monotonicity and iterate `while a**3 < x:` to find the interval that contains the cube root.

---

To be faster, start with a geometric progression

```
a=b=1
while b<x: a*=2; b*=8
```

and then continue the search inside the interval $[a/2,a]$.

Using pure "function table lookup", for monotonous functions the bisection method is still the fastest.

Using the smoothness of the cube function, using secant roots or tangent roots as midpoints in an intelligent way will again increase the speed of convergence.

A very fast convergence is obtained from applying Newton's method to $f(a)=a^2-x/a$

Comment: I understand, the net analogy helps. Is Daniel's comment conveying the same thing? I cannot find an $x$ and $n$ that satisfy $x-0.2<(n/100)^3<x-0.01$.

Comment: Yes, this aims to find an $x$ that falls in such a gap. $n$ needs to be large enough for such a gap to open, about $3n^2>0.2·100^3$, which is the case for $n>300$. Indeed between $3^3=27$ and $(3.01)^3=27.271$ the gap is large enough, $x=27.15$ for example can not be reached.